# Printing a variable from a dictionary gives an error and says it doesn't exist

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, output

I'm trying to print a variable that's stored in a dictionary, but when I try to print it, it says:

> ```
>   File "C:\Users\defomyname\Desktop\thing.py", line 24, in <module>
> main()   File "C:\Users\defomyname\Desktop\thing.py", line 20, in main
> print(f"Value 1: {settings.value1}") AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value1'. >Did you mean: 'values'?
> ```

Code:

```
is_on = None
value1 = None
value2 = None

settings = {
    is_on: False,
    value1: 10,
    value2: 20
}



def main():
    #print(f"Enabled: {settings.is_on}")
    print(f"----------------")
    print(f"Value 1: {settings.value1}")
    print(f"Value 2: {settings.value2}")
    print("-----------------")

main()
```

Comment: `settings.value1` is attribute syntax. For dictionary lookup, use `settings['value1']`.

Comment: It gives me another problem with "is_on", it prints out "20" even thought it should print out "False"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning repetitive identical keys to a dictionary.
the dictionnary structure in Python is designed to have only unique and distinct keys.
Your code is basically like this:

```
settings = {
None : False,
None : 10,
None : 20
}
```

Now, if you print again the settings variable, the `None` key will only be assigned to 20 because it was the last assignment.

this is the current state of `settings`:

```
settings = {None: 20}
```

Finally, the `settings` variable is dictionnary. and dictionnaries has only 3 attributes:

1. keys() : list of the `settings` keys:

```
print(settings.keys())
```

2. values() : list of its values:

```
print(settings.values())
```

3. items() : list of its items (key, value):

```
print(settings.items())
```

output:

```
dict_keys([None])
dict_values([20])
dict_items([(None, 20)])
```

the values of a specific key can be obtained by `settings[None]`.

Comment: So you're basically saying that since the value of "is_on", "value1" and "value2" are all the same therefore the dictionary only has 1 value/thing stored in it?
(sorry if i misunderstand anything I struggle with understanding things due to asd)

Comment: Yes, your dictionary has only 1 item (key/value), the key is `None` and the value is the last value assigned to `None` which is `20`. Don't worry, it's allright we were all beginners.